# oracle query to get sum of columns which has different values

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having oracle table like below

```
TestId   TestName    Count

101       PRD         10    
102       PRD         20
102       TEST        30
103       TEST        40
```

expected results would be,

```
  TestId    Count
  
  101       10
  102       50
  103       40
```

Can you please help with the oracle query?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
SELECT TESTID, SUM(COUNT)
FROM table
GROUP BY TESTID
```

You might have to change the column name "count" to something else.

Hope this is what you were looking for!